# How to download a file from Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am currently trying to make an application that downloads files from Google Drive.

In the Google Drive SDK documentation I found an example method that should return a System.IO.Stream object.

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads

To do so it needs the download URL for each file.
However, this download URL is not always specified returned. Does anyone have any Idea why this is? And what I can do about it?

Update: I have found that I can use an exportURL. These are almost always returned by the service.

Folowup question: How can I run an app as a certain user? => sometimes the app makes a request to a url and then the request times out. When I try that same URL in a browser it works like a charm...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have a downloadlink if the file you are trying to download is a native google docs format. If that's the case you must look for the exportLinks.

You will have several export links, so you will have to choose which format suits you best : docx or odt for document for example

Comment: I was just typing the same thing in my question :)

Now I have another issue however. Sometimes the request times out and I don't really know why because the exportlinks work why I try them in a browser.

Comment: I've never experienced any timeout. Random server errors happen though. You should implement Exponential backoff, there is an example in the Drive API documentation

Comment: I have marked this answer as the correct answer because it helped me to get further on. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Might be late but I just downloaded from Google Drive using the following code:

```
var stream = service.HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(downloadUrl);
        var result = stream.Result;
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
        {
            result.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
```

Comment: can you tell me what library should be added to get "service.HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(downloadUrl);"?

Comment: @Santarkantos, in Sando's example "service" is an instance of DriveService, which comes from the Google Drive API. You can pull the libraries into your project using NuGet and searching for Google.Apis.Drive.v2.