# How to download a public shared file from google drive with C#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download a public shared file from Google Drive using C#.

Here's the code I'm currently using

```
DriveService.Files.Get(fileId);
```

Where the `fileID` is taken from the URL

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/{ fileID }/view?usp=sharing
```

Now this all seems like it should work no problem, but I'm getting a file not found error every time.

I've done this previously with getting a list of files from a public folder that is shared and I managed to get that one working by using this query

```
ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
request.Q = $"'{ folderID }' in parents";
request.Fields = "files(mimeType,id,modifiedTime,name,version,originalFilename)";
```

The `in parents` section is what made this one work, but I can't think of a similar way to make the `Get` query work, it seems like it should just work if given the right ID and I have the permissions.

I'm definitely logged in correctly, as I'm able to download other files, so I know that's not the problem either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents) if it will works on you stated that to Downloading Google Documents, use the files.export method. Exports use the same alt=media approach as downloading other content in Drive. There is a .NET code example for it. For more information, check this [tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-download/) and [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025053).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being related to permission scopes when authenticating through `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()`.

I'd played with these previously, and I thought it just didn't work, but it turns out you have to delete any previous credentials for these changes to actually work. See the comments [in google's sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet).

To read public files I had to add the following permission to my scope

```
DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly
```

Hopefully nobody else will stare at their screen for hours now.

Answer (score 0):

The File Resource returned by `request.Execute();` contains a `WebContentLink` property. It is a link for downloading the content using cookie based authentication. In cases where the content is shared publicly, the content can be downloaded without any credentials.

Or you could just do (in API v2):

```
var request = MyService.Files.Get(FileID);
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

try
{
    request.Download(stream);
    System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(PathToSave, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
    Stream.WriteTo(file);
    file.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Occured:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

You won't have a downloadlink if the file you are trying to download is a native Google Docs format. If that's the case you must look for the `ExportLinks`.

You will have several export links, so you will have to choose which format suits you best.

Comment: This won't work. I'm still getting a file not found error.

Comment: Code above is tested and working. You must be doing something else wrong..

Comment: My point is that I already have code just like this. When downloading project files that were created through my app, I have no problem with this code. I think my issue is that I'm not able to find the file as stated in the question, for some reason this public file can't be found.

Comment: Alright. Seems like issue's with the file ID. Are you sure you're taking the file ID correctly? Please update the question with your relevant code.

Comment: Finally figured it out, all to do with scopes. Thanks for trying.